# PHP string cut off when emailed: simple bug fix help please

Tags: php, post

There's a comment card feature on the website I work at, that after filling out the forms, a php mail call is made to email people the comments. However, one of the strings, "comments" is getting cut off. Could someone look at this code and possibly tell me why?
EDIT: Did some testing and discovered that single and double quotes cause the problem. Any advice on dealing with this would be great. Do I want to use stripslashes or some such?

Here is an example of the problem:

```
Location: The place
Quality: Good
Comments: The Hot Dog at the Grill was labeled with the \\
Email: someemail@email.com
Date: 05/23/11
Time: 13:34
```

Here is the confirmation page: (help much appreciated, it's my first day on the job and I can't figure this out!

```
<?php
$date=date("m/d/y");
$time=date("H:i");
$loc=$_POST['location'];
$qual=$_POST['quality'];
$comm=$_POST['comments'];
$em=$_POST['email'];

echo("<p class=\"bodytext\">You are about to send the following information:<span><br><br><span class=\"bodytextbold\">Location:</span> ".$loc."<br><br><span class=\"bodytextbold\">How was your food?:</span>".$qual."<br><br><span class=\"bodytextbold\">Comments: </span>".$comm."<br><br><span class=\"bodytextbold\">Your email address: ".$em);
echo("<form method=\"post\" action=\"comment_card_email.html\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"location\" value=\"".$loc."\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"quality\" value=\"".$qual."\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"comments\" value=\"".$comm."\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"email\" value=\"".$em."\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"date\" value=\"".$date."\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"time\" value=\"".$time."\">
<input type=\"submit\" class=\"bodytext\" value=\"submit comments\" name=\"submit\"></form>");
?>
```

And here's the html page php script that receives it:

```
<?php
$location = $_POST['location'];
$quality = $_POST['quality'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$recipients = "someemail@email.com";

function mail_staff($recipients, $location, $quality, $comments, $email, $date, $time){
    mail($recipients, "Comment Card#[".$location."]".time(), "The following comment has been submitted:

Location: $location
Quality: $quality
Comments: $comments
Email: $email
Date: $date
Time: $time

", "From:".$email);
}
```

Comment: Do the comments *always* get cut off, or just under certain conditions? Are you sure it's not a word-wrapping issue?

Comment: I noticed that you're submitting the form to "comment_card_email.html" - which is not a php file. how come ? also - can you show us where exactly it's being cut off ?

Comment: Just under certain conditions. However, I'm unsure of which conditions these are; the staff have only provided me with that one example. They said that sometimes the comment is fine, and other times it's cut off with the \\. Any help would be much appreciated, or guidelines of where to look. Thanks Brian!

Comment: alfasin - Comments: The Hot Dog at the Grill was labeled with the \\. That's literally what people receieve, is that what you're asking? I'm not sure about your question about submitting to comment_card_email.html..is that not okay? It has the above php script within it.

Comment: Might want to try heredoc for that long echo statement, will make it much cleaner and easier. As to your problem, the only thing I can think of is that the comments are just too long to be stored in that particular variable. May be wrong, wont know for sure without a sample $comments

Comment: Your comment about the \\ makes me think you've escaped the rest of the string. Make sure your quotes aren't causing issues

Comment: Thanks showerhead I'll try that. The thing is, everything shows up fine on the confirmation page, but it's just cut off in the email. Does this indicate a problem with the second script I posted?

Comment: @Ken you might need to do some testing for yourself to reproduce the problem. My gut says that the comment string is being terminated because of an unescaped double-quote.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Brian, I'll start doing some testing. This is my first day on the job working at a place like this and I'm the only techie person (I'm a student). They have the files on winscp. Is the best way to test, just to make local copies of everything?

Comment: Also here are more examples of comments: I am writing this comment in response to the poor service provided at Ramona\\\'s last week. I occasionally stop by on my way to my 8am class, which I must get to by 7:30 in order to take down the notes my professor posts before class. I was in a hurry on this particular day, but I noticed there was no line because it was so early so I stopped by to purchase a drink. I grabbed my drink from the fridge and went to the cash register where a cashier was standing, but just as I put out my ID card to be swiped she said \\

Comment: Yea from the look of that comment, it looks like the user used a double quote there. Try using htmlspecialchars to escape those quotes instead.

Comment: I did some testing, and indeed, double quotes and single quotes cause some crazy ///'s. What do you mean by htmlspecialchars? how do I change the code from how it works now? I thought php took care of the details of escaping.

Comment: As the users' comments can be long, maybe you should use textareas instead of text inputs, it would prevent the possible conflict with the double quotes surrounding the inputs' value attribute and double quotes inside the value (easy way ^^). Also, in your last code (the one that receives POST and sends the e-mail), you may have to unescape the POST parameters before passing them to mail() (depending on the magic_quotes_runtime configuration on the server).

Comment: [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is a PHP function that escapes HTML friendly entities from text. So the quotes would be in the &xxxx; format. Thus you would not need to worry about escaping any longer as that would be taken care of with entities. And its reversible with [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)... I'm going to move all of this into an answer so its easier to find rather than looking through all these comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Went ahead and pulled my comments together and combined them into this answer.

You might want to consider using heredoc for those long echo statements, it will make it much cleaner and easier.

```
echo <<<FORM
<form method="post" action="comment_card_email.html">
<input type="hidden" name="location" value="$loc">
<input type="hidden" name="quality" value="$qual">
<input type="hidden" name="comments" value="$comm">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="$em">
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="$date">
<input type="hidden" name="time" value="$time">
<input type="submit" class="bodytext" value="submit comments" name="submit"></form>
FORM;
```

Your comment about the "\" makes me think that you've accidentally escaped the rest of the string. Make sure your quotes aren't causing issues. From the look of your sample comment, it looks like the user used a double quote and that escaped the rest of your string. Try using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to escape those quotes instead. htmlspecialchars is a PHP function that escapes HTML friendly entities from text. So the quotes would be in the &xxxx; format. Thus you would not need to worry about escaping quotes any longer as that would be taken care of with entities. And its reversible with [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php). So this should work.

```
$raw = $_POST['comments'];
$stripped = stripslashes($_POST['comments'];
$comments = htmlspecialchars($stripped, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Edit: Oops, the form didn't go through for the heredoc, edited it to work.

Comment: Thanks shower head! I tried changing from $comments = $_POST['comments'] to $comments = htmlspecialchars($_POST['comments'], ENT_QUOTES), but it had no effect - how come? stripslashes works, but it doesn't solve my emailing problem, just the way it displays on the confirmation page.

Comment: stripslashes and then use htmlspecialchars.

Comment: Also, I agree with alfasin and Stock Overflaw, you might want to make those changes if you get the chance. alfasin was saying that PHP scripts are usually stored in a PHP file rather than HTML and he was surprised that your script worked at all because of the wrong extension. Stock brings up a good point about the textarea being better.

Comment: Awesome. You guys are super helpful thanks! Especially props to showerhead for so much advice.